# Kinetic Friction during turning around a road

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, centripetal-force

If a body is sliding in a circle, where the road has some non-zero friction, obviously there exists some static friction towards the radius, as the relative motion in the radial direction is zero, but a tendency exists. However, in the tangential direction, is friction zero or does some kinetic friction act to resist its velocity? In other words, is there no tangential relative motion present?